# Proper way to handle SSL Certs in Kestrel/Docker production

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm familiar with creating the localhost development certs with dev-certs but that isn't helping me when moving to a non development environment.  I'm able to deploy the ASP.NET Core 5.0/React app to Windows 2019 successfully and it serves up the site on the http.  On the https port I'm getting a certificate error, invalid cert authority.  This makes sense because I'm trying to use one of those localhost dev certs when I do the docker run with a volume to the cert location on the host.

When this site is served up, it's not using localhost to the outside, it's obviously using the server's IP address.  I've also tried exporting other Trusted Root certificates to no avail because they come up with a different domain than this server.

So I'm supposing at this point I need a tried and true certificate authority.  I don't know if I can make a cert request because this container host has no way of reaching outside the firewall to the public internet.  Any ideas? If you need more info, be happy to provide.